# what is the difference between EPOLL File descriptor and event file descriptor?

Tags: linux, pthreads, epoll

i am using EPOLL and eventfd for IPC in threads but i am not getting the differences between the arguments epoll file descriptor and event file descriptor

can you please elaborate...

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**epoll file descriptor** : system call :

```
      int epoll_create1(int flags);
```

returns the `epoll` file descriptor, also called `efd`. This descriptor is use for polling(`epoll_wait`) and control(epoll_ctl) commands.

**event file descriptor** : Normal socket fd return from `socket` or `accept` like system calls knows as `event` file descriptor. These file descriptors are set events like `EPOLLIN`, `EPOLLOUT` ,`EPOLLET` etc..

event file descriptors are register or bind on event file descriptor for polling the events.